# PRODUCED DISTINCT RECORD WITH MULTIPLE FIELDS

Tags: sql-server, distinct

Im trying to figure out how i could pull out the data out of this table:

Table: Status

```
OrderNo   Status   Date        User
1          1       2011-07-01  user1
1          2       2011-07-05  user1
2          1       2011-07-01  user1
2          2       2011-07-06  user2
2          3       2011-07-10  user1
```

and i need to produce the following result:

```
OrderNo   Status   Date        User
1          2       2011-07-05  user1
2          3       2011-07-10  user1
```

Actually, what i needed is to display  DISTINCT list of OrderNo and thier last status.

Thanks for all the possible help.

Cheers!

Comment: See this example please: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/1002/630

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH S AS
(
    SELECT OrderNo, Status, Date, User
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER
          (
              PARTITION BY OrderNo
              ORDER BY Date DESC
          ) Ranking
    FROM Status
)
SELECT OrderNo, Status, Date, User
FROM S
WHERE Ranking = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select OrderNo, max(Status) as 'Status'
from Status
group by OrderNo
```

Comment: I assume you haven't tested this... what about Date and User columns? -1 because doesn't deserve an upvote

Comment: i agree..it was only a tentative answer (but no test is required to see that Date and User aren't there...anyway i tested it:)