# Finding correct record using MAX(date)

Tags: mysql

I've run into this problem that I've struggled with for some time now, reading a lot of post but not being able to solve it by my self.

I've a table holding record of members status changes in a club. "Status_Members"

```
MemberID     Date       StatusID

23         2011-04-01      1
46         2011-05-01      2
23         2011-10-01      2
46         2011-06-01      1
```

This is joined to a table "Status_Type" holding the values of the StatusID.

```
StatusID     StatusName
1             Active
2             Passive
```

Joining the 2 together gives:

```
MemberID     Date       StatusName
23         2011-04-01      Active
46         2011-05-01      Passive
23         2011-10-01      Passive
46         2011-06-01      Active
```

Now I want to be able to find the status of the members on a specific date.

Let's say 2011-07-01.

So I tried with this code:

```
SELECT S.MemberID, MAX(Date), ST.StatusName FROM Status_Members S, Status_Type ST
WHERE ST.StatusId=S.StatusID
AND
Date <= '2011-07-01'
Group By MemberID
Order by Date DESC
```

So I expect the result to be:

```
MemberID, MAX(Date), StatusName

46       2011-06-01   Active
23       2011-04-01   Active
```

But I get this "wrong" result

```
MemberID, MAX(Date), StatusName

46       2011-06-01   Passive
23       2011-04-01   Active
```

Why am I getting the result Passive instead of Active on MemberID 46 ??

Can Anyone help me out here???

Best regard a Newbie

Comment: Take a look into this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787132/produced-distinct-record-with-multiple-fields

Answer (score 2):

When you aggregate with `MAX`, you don't have control over the representative row that you're getting which isn't being aggregated or gouped by, namely your status ID. So make two queries and join them:

```
SELECT sm.MemberID AS MemberId, MaxDate, StatusName
FROM Status_Type AS st
JOIN Status_Members AS sm ON (st.StatusId = sm.StatusId)
JOIN (SELECT MemberID, MAX(Date) AS MaxDate FROM Status_Members WHERE Date <= xxx GROUP BY MemberID) AS sq
  ON (sm.MemberId = sq.MemberId AND sm.Date = sq.MaxDate);
```

The subquery makes an intermediate table `MemberId, MaxDate`, and we join that again the `Member_Status` table again to retrieve the status at that date.

Comment: Hi Kerrek This works perfect. Thank you so much, I can see why It didn't work now. Thanks for a good explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you `GROUP BY` member.id. Your MAX() function thus returns the MAX-date for a given member, which for `46` is `2011-06-01`. It should not return `ST.StatusName` as it is not part of an aggregate function or your `GROUP BY`, so I guess it just takes the first occurence.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to `GROUP` also `BY` the statusName?

```
SELECT S.MemberID, MAX(Date) as maxDate, ST.StatusName FROM Status_Members S, Status_Type ST
WHERE ST.StatusId=S.StatusID
GROUP BY MemberID, StatusName
HAVING maxDate <= '2011-07-01'
ORDER By Date DESC
```